# How check the file is corrupted before concatenate them with FFmpeg?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, child-process

I'm using `child_process` package in NodeJS to run FFmpeg for concatenating some videos. The command that I use for concatenating is:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list_file.txt -c copy final.mp4
```

that `list_file.txt` is the list of videos file and it contains:

```
file '700010023590099933_1612945401707.mp4'
file '700010023590099933_1612945439023.mp4'
.
.
```

I want to check every video before concatenate them because if one of them be corrupted it stops the process and throws an error. So it makes the final video corrupted too.

In addition, I can check if a video file is OK or not with this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -f null -; echo $?
```

that returns `0` if file is OK and `1` if not.

I want to check all the video files and if all of them are OK then concatenate them. And if each one was corrupted then exclude it and continue the process.
Is there a way to do this in one command?

Comment: So, what do you do, if one of the videos is corrupt? Exclude it from concatenation? Don't do the concatenation at all? If the latter, why bothering at all? If the concatenation throws an error, just throw away the result.

Comment: Definitely, exclude that one.

Comment: @derpirscher Thank you. I mentioned that in question.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the text file, parse it and spawn for each video file a test process.

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const cp = require("child_process");

const fileContent = fs.readFileSync("./videos.txt", "utf8").split("\n").map((line) => {
    return line.match(/'([^']+)'/)[1];
});


const filterd = fileContent.filter((file) => {

    let corrupt = cp.execSync(`ffmpeg -i ./${file} -c copy -f null -; echo $?`, {
        stdio: "pipe",
        encoding: "utf8"
    }).trim();

    // corrupt = 0, file is ok, use it
    // corrupt = 1, file is corrupt, ignore it
    if (corrupt !== "0") {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

});

// contains only fiels without error
console.log(filterd)
```

First, read the file via `fs.readFileSync` and do some string manipluation on it the get only the file names we need/want.

Out of the parsed file, a array gets generated, over which we can use filter.
In the filter creteria we simple call the ffmpeg test process and do basic string comparsion to check if the file is useable or not.

The `filterd` array just contains file names that can be processed.
(Use full if you want to show what files can be used or not)

Out of that array you can now create a new file or pass it directly as file/input argument to ffmepg

```js
var parseableFiles = "";

filterd.forEach((file) => {
    parseableFiles += `file '${file}'\r\n`;
});

fs.writeFileSync("./filterd_files.txt", parseableFiles);
```

Note that i wrote all function calls syncron. This blocks the event loop.
Also keep in mind that new line `\r\n` are diffrent on other opertings system. -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation

Coded & Tested on Ubuntu 18.04LTS.

Comment: Yes, I already did that not exactly like you said though. But I just wanted to know there is a better way or not. Thank you so much.